# Careers 2 Advertising

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, jobs

Whilst browsing questions within a tag on Stack Overflow, there is always a Careers 2 advert on the right hand pane. The thing is, that the advertised jobs never relate to me, or the tag that I am browsing.

Would it not be fairly straight forward, good for Stack Careers and good for the users if you targeted the jobs to the tag(s) being browsed? I for one would find that very useful.

Comment: This is by design. From intensive analysis of your behaviour and what you expose of yourself on the 'net, Careers *knows which job you should enter, and which technologies you should learn next*.

Comment: So it already uses content targeting? If so, why would it only ever show me Java, C# and PHP jobs when I live on the SQL Sever tag and spend the rest of my online life consuming SQL Server and SSIS content?

Comment: Nah, just kidding. So it's not showing targeted jobs for you? That's strange, it does for me. Maybe there are not enough jobs in the tags you specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've tried what you're suggesting before and it didn't work out well. We found that  attempting to target job ads to the tags of the questions you're viewing performed poorly vs other targeting strategies (by somewhere around 3-5 to 1 if I'm remembering my analysis correctly). It's not that we aren't attempting to show you job ads relevant to you, it's just by looking at data in the aggregate targeting by skills related to the questions you're looking at isn't the best way to do it.